# select data which has on json data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this JSON data on user table feild name 'pincodes': "["712401","712415"]"
[image]

and I have an order table: which contains 'pincodes' field on database.

I want data from order table whose pincode has on "["712401","712415"]"

```
public function orders()
 {
     $pincodes = Auth::user()->pin_codes;
        
     $order_list = Order::whereJsonContains('pin_code',$pincodes)->get();
     //dd($order_list);
     return view('delivery.orders', compact('order_list'));
 }
```

Comment: If your field name is `pincodes`, then why are you using `whereJsonContains('pin_code', ...)`? `'pincodes'` and `'pin_code'` are not the same thing...

Comment: pincodes is on users table, and pincode is on orders table

Comment: `pincodes`, `pin_codes`, `pin_code`, and now `pincode`... That's now 4 different versions  You need to figure out what you're trying to access/query here.

Comment: I didn't say what you understood

Comment: You have listed `pincode` in 4 different variations now; `pincode`, `pincodes`, `pin_code` and `pin_codes`; you need to figure out which field belongs to which model, and query for that appropriately. I can't help you when your code/explanation is as confusing as it is, sorry.